# Verify your WordPress sub domain with Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, wordpress, migration

My question is similar to [The SEO Impact of Migrating from Free Hosting on WordPress.com to Own Hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44881/the-seo-impact-of-migrating-from-free-hosting-on-wordpress-com-to-own-hosting) but it was answered in 2013 and I am afraid things have changed.

Basically I have a Wordpress subdomain `mydom.wordpress.com`, which has some trafic I want to redirect to a static website.

I have the free plan of Wordpress. I tried to upgrade to "Business", but as I wanted to install the plugins that enable to :

> Verify your WordPress sub domain with Google Webmaster Tools

I am asked to change domain (in something like `mydom.blog`). If I do so, I would lose all my backlinks.

Has anyone successfully migrated from a wordpress blog to a website without losing to much ranking ?

Comment: It costs you $13 per year to redirect away from free WordPress hosting: https://en.support.wordpress.com/site-redirect/  See also: [Can you use an external 301 redirect for a blog post hosted on wordpress.com?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100399/can-you-use-an-external-301-redirect-for-a-blog-post-hosted-on-wordpress-com)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Wordpress developed a specific feature to do this in `/settings/traffic/` with a specific placeholder for various search engines meta tags.