# Can redirecting away from WordPress.com with a "Poor Man's Redirect" preserve SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, wordpress, migration

My situation is the following: I have a WordPress free blog that I want to migrate to a static HTML site. However, I cannot execute PHP on this WordPress domain*, therefore, the solution proposed here: [The SEO Impact of Migrating from Free Hosting on WordPress.com to Own Hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44881/the-seo-impact-of-migrating-from-free-hosting-on-wordpress-com-to-own-hosting) does not apply (at least, does not apply any longer).

I am considering doing a "poor man's redirect", as describe here: [Can you use an external 301 redirect for a blog post hosted on wordpress.com?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100399/can-you-use-an-external-301-redirect-for-a-blog-post-hosted-on-wordpress-com) How bad would it be?

*Strictly speaking, I could pay to execute PHP code on WordPress. But if I want to install my plugin, I will have to change my domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, my solution (the Poor Man’s Redirect) would not preserve SEO. By destroying the content on the WordPress.com site, you remove it’s relevancy to search engines.  The content on the external site would become the indexed content and might get a small boost from link juice, but that’s it.